Snowflake SQL Procedure CALL using OBJECT CONSTRUCT
I'm trying to create a snowflake procedure in SQL which takes two inputs (first is table_name and second is object where key is column_name and value is 1,2,3 etc.,). When the value is 1, then it should check if there are more than 10% null values in that column and return message based on successful and failed validations.
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE
GARDEN_PLANTS.VEGGIES.MY_PROC(table_name VARCHAR,
rule_object OBJECT)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE SQL
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 

    DECLARE
        column_name VARCHAR;
        rule_value INTEGER;
        null_percent FLOAT;
        total_rows FLOAT;
        null_count FLOAT;
        null_query CURSOR FOR SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name  WHERE column_name IS NULL;
        total_query CURSOR FOR SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name;
    BEGIN
        FOR column_name IN OBJECT_KEYS(rule_object)
        DO
            rule_value := GET(rule_object, column_name)::INT;
            OPEN null_query;
            FETCH null_query INTO null_count;
            OPEN total_query;
            FETCH total_query INTO total_rows;
            
            null_percent := (null_count/total_rows)*100;
            
            IF (rule_value = 1) THEN
                IF (null_percent > 10) THEN
                    RETURN 'More than 10% null values.';
                ELSE
                    RETURN 'More than 10% null values.';
                END IF;
            END IF;
            CLOSE total_query;
            CLOSE null_query;
        END FOR;
        RETURN  'No valid rule';
    END;


CALL GARDEN_PLANTS.VEGGIES.MY_PROC('ROOT_DEPTH', OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('ROOT_DEPTH_CODE', 1))

Root depth tables has ROOT_DEPTH_CODE column where there are more than 50% nulls. But when I'm calling the procedure I'm getting key error.

Can you share the error?  Also, you should edit your post so that all of the code is in the code block.

100069 (22P02): Uncaught exception of type 'EXPRESSION_ERROR' on line 12 at position 17 : Error parsing JSON: unknown keyword "ROOT_DEPTH_CODE", pos 16. I also tried without using Object construct as input and updated code to use table_name and column_name then I'm getting unknown table or not authorized. When I give table and column name in the SQL statement inside the cursor then I'm getting my result

Odd that SELECT GET(OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('ROOT_DEPTH_CODE', 1), 'ROOT_DEPTH_CODE')::INT works as expected, but it seems like that is where you are getting the error. Also, unrelated, I feel like you will need to use dynamic SQL to make those cursors work since it's the table_name and column_name that are changing inside the loop and, to my knowledge, you can parameterize a sql object (table, column, view, etc) in SQL.
